# spring security admin gateway and angularjs exception

Tags: angularjs, spring, security, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I am using gateway based authentication in spring security. A user is authenticated from the database. Through zuul, the authenticated user is directed to the UI microservice. A successfully authenticates user at the admin gateway service when routed to the UI microservice gives the following exception.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysecurity.CustomUserDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your exception:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysecurity.CustomUserDetails`

Just make sure that you have `mysecurity.CustomUserDetails` class in your classpath